# Reentering Schengen Zone with a new stamp

Tags: schengen

I entered the Schengen zone on September 29th, 2016 and left on November 20th, 2016 spending 53 days in Sweden and Spain. Let's say I want to return to Europe.
I have 37 days left on my 180 day period which ends on March 29th, 2017. Can I go to Morocco before the 180 days expires, travel for a week, and return to Spain after March 29th and get a new stamp starting a new 180 day period during which I can travel in Europe another 90 days?

I read a comment that if you do this, after the second period expires, you have to stay out of the Schengen zone for 6 consecutive months. Is this correct?

Comment: No, it's not correct. You seem to have some of the rules criss-crossed. It might be best if you used the Schengen calculator.  https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en

Answer (score 7):

That's not how it works. [You get 90/180 days on a rolling basis](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/docs/short_stay_schengen_calculator_user_manual_en.pdf). In other words, at any given time, you can only spend 90 out of the last 180 days inside the Schengen zone. If you've been in the Schengen zone and then spend 90 days out of the zone, you've essentially reset your clock and get another 90 days.

There's [a calculator](https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en) you can use to work out how many days you have at any given time.

If your nationality requires a visa to visit the Schengen area, the terms of your visa may be more restrictive than the general 90/180 day rule. If this applies, please post the details of your visa (a picture with your personal information redacted would be best), and we can take a look at that too.

Since you mention stamps, I should clarify that you will receive a new stamp every time you enter or exit the Schengen zone. The stamp shows the current date, not the date you must leave by.